# Number sequence of measured samples

Tags: matlab

So need a little help here, solution is probably super simple.

I have an array of values in Matlab that represent measured sample IDs. Each sample is measured `n` number of times (usually four, but not always). A set of measurements of a sample represent a sequence, where each individual measurement is a cycle. I then move onto the next sample and perform the same operation. Once each sample has been measured, I repeat the process again, so each sample is measured multiple times, made up of `n` cycles that make up a sequence. I need to assign a sequence number to a group of cycles. How is this best accomplished in Matlab? An example partial array is shown.

`id = [134950
134950
134950
134950
134951
134951
134951
134951
134736
134736
134736
134736
134737
134737
134737
134737
123841
123841
123841
123841]`

So each set of unique IDs is a sequence.

I've tried `logical(diff(id))` but I cant think of a good way to increment the sequence number.

To follow up, what I am looking for would be the creation of a vector of same dimension as id, but would be composed of something like

`seq =[1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5]`

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for? Something like this:

```
sequence = [1; find(logical(diff(id)))];
```

Edit:

Based on your feedback, this is easy. Just use the `unique` function.

```
[~, ~, sequence] = unique(id,'stable')
```

Comment: Not quite. I've edited my original post to hopefully clarify a bit more. Thanks, again.

Comment: Oh my, thanks so much. I had tried unique previously, but I guess I didnt quite get the options correct.